# <mvc:annotation-driven /> shows compile time error

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
                        >
```

This is my schema declaration. But  mvc:annotation-driven  it shows compile time error. 
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element.  I could not find the problem properly. So please help for finding this problem.

Error: 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.
Can you please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven /> this tag shows error... But beans schema it does not show any error. So please look at this. give solution..

Answer (score 4):

You are probably missing spring-webmvc-*.jar file in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

just created this:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"

> 

and trivial code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("1.xml").getBeanDefinitionCount() );
}
```

This shows 0 without error, so really this is because missing of spring-mvc jar as per @Biju Kunjummen(+1)

Also you may have 2 different versions of spring-mvc...

Comment: org.springframework.web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar  But i have this two jars.. This is enough for this. right..

Comment: i am not sure what is spring-web-servlet, but you need to add this one http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar

Comment: when i run this main method i got Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException. Even I given absolute path...